# iOS Different tabs point to the same view

Tags: ios, swift3, tabs, navigation

I am working on an app with 3 tabs: Purchases, Library and Search. Each tab will have a table view with a list of episodes (the information in the cells will vary depending on what the active tab is). Each of the three View Controllers is embedded in its own navigation controller.

So that's: 
Purchases Tab -> Navigation Controller -> Table View -> Episode Detail View
Search Tab -> Navigation Controller -> Table View -> Episode Detail View

The thing is that in the detail view for more than one of these would be basically the same (if I click on an item in the Purchases list I'd get the same view than I'd get if I clicked on a search result).

What would be the best way to achieve this, do I put clones of the episode detail view for each branch (so, for example, placing a detail VC after Search and then placing a detail VC that's practically identical after Purchases)? Or is there a way to, for example, make the search item go to the detail view that I placed after Purchases?

My concern is that I want to preserve the navigation, so if I'm on the Search tab and I click on an item and get the detail view, when I click back I should be taken to the previous screen still within Search, not within some other tab.

All my views are in storyboard. I'm working on Swift 3 / iOS 10 / XCode 8.3.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me. You can do it with Storyboard connected Segues or via code.

[image]

Just try it and see for yourself...